# Can I count characters of half of div container with jquery?

Tags: jquery, text, count

I have an div with some random text ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw1v361f/2/)).

The height of container is `397px`. Half of container height is `198.5px`. How to count the symbols of `198.5px` of container with jquery, is it possible?

Comment: I'd suggest you split it into two different `<span>` or `<div>`s for simplicity, but someone creative could probably find a way.

Comment: you can not divide px ... its the base unit and +int

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is a better way around it. The problem you are describing is quite difficult, since there are many variables: font size, line height, screen pixel density etc. Catching all the edge cases is quite labor intensive project.

Comment: Sounds like typical XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem